# Is Herb Sutter's code joke in GotW #35 on typename out of date?

Tags: c++, typename

I was reading one of the old Guru of the Week articles on `typename`, [#35](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/035.htm). At the very end, you can find the following snippet:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using std::cout;
> using std::endl;
>
> struct Rose {};
>
> struct A { typedef Rose rose; };
>
> template<class T>
> struct B : T { typedef typename T::rose foo; };
>
> template<class T>
> void smell( T ) { cout << "awful" << endl; }
>
> void smell( Rose ) { cout << "sweet" << endl; }
>
> int main() {
>     smell( A::rose() );
>     smell( B<A>::foo() );
> }
> ```

I don't get this. My first guess was that the second `smell` invocation led to the template `smell` being instantiated due to something you easily overlook (what should the joke be about, otherwise?!). But both calls lead to "sweet" being printed out. And isn't that to be expected, after all? In `typedef Rose rose;`, `Rose` is not a dependent name, so that's fine. In `typedef typename T::rose foo;`, `rose` is dependent, but `typename` mitigates that. My question(s):

1. What's the point of this snippet? Am I missing a sense of humour here?
2. The article is from 1998; were there any language changes that alter what this code does?

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/_7vX5e) is a condensed version of the snippet on godbolt. I tested every compiler that looked old (e.g. `gcc-4.4.1`, but note that the above snippet is still 11 years older than `gcc-4.4.1`).

Comment: The joke is a reference to ["A rose by any other name would smell as sweet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet)

Comment: @interjay Ha, thanks. That means what this snippet does is as expected and what I'm missing here is being a man of vast reading? How depressing. Why don't you turn this comment into an answer?

Comment: What's funny is that that line is from the 'English literary canon' which children in Britain and its former colonies are forced to endure* in school.  For fluent English speakers outside of those regions, that English heritage thing really isn't important, so it would make sense that you wouldn't be familiar.  (*Shakespeare's plays are fun to watch but the scripts are boring to read.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your understanding of the code is correct. The joke here is a reference to the line from Shakespeare's Romeo and Julliet:

> What's in a name? That which we call a rose
>   By any other name would smell as sweet;

Which is often paraphrased as "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet."

Or in the case of this code:

> `A::Rose`, by any other type name, would still make `smell()` print `"sweet"`.